# How can I show a line under each row of text in a Spark TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I'm trying to show a horizontal line under each row of text in a Spark TextArea. I want to give the text area the look of legal paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah actually ran into a similar problem in Flex 3 doing a strikeout for a disabled link-button that was part of our styles.  Just checked out the code and looked on the docs for the spark label and found the function I was using from a mx label explicitly says it won't work [from measureText() in spark label]:

> Measures the specified text, assuming that it is displayed in a
>   single-line UITextField (or UIFTETextField) using a UITextFormat
>   determined by the styles of this UIComponent. Does not work for Spark
>   components since they don't use UITextField (or UIFTETextField). To
>   measure text in Spark components, get the measurements of a
>   spark.components.Label or spark.components.RichText

So I re-figured it out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Label xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth : Number, unscaledHeight : Number) : void
            {
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                drawLines();
            }

            private function drawLines() : void
            {
                var totalHeight : Number = 0;
                for (var i : int = 0; i < mx_internal::textLines.length; i++)
                {

                    totalHeight = mx_internal::textLines[i].y;
                    graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
                    graphics.moveTo(0, totalHeight);
                    graphics.lineTo(width, totalHeight);
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the [textDecoration](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#style%3atextDecoration) style for the control.