# Underline style for text/labels in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, text, underline

I use the setStyle("textDecoration", "underline"); for showing an underline on text hover.
This works fine but the underline is touching the text itself. Is it possible to put some spacing between text and the underline?

Update: 02/072012
I'm using Flex SDK 3.5 so I cant use the spark solution for now. Im using Label component and setting the textfield's style.

Comment: What kind of component are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it isn't an ideal solution I recently answered a question that had somewhat similar requirements.  Please be specific with regard to the Flex SDK version you're using as these things vary from one to the next on occasion.

[How can I show a line under each row of text in a Spark TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072107/how-can-i-show-a-line-under-each-row-of-text-in-a-spark-textarea/9074107#9074107)

I'm not aware off hand of any style that specifically specifies the distance of the line from the text (I believe this might be part of the font definition itself, somehow using the ascent value or something along those lines though I'm not entirely sure as I haven't dug through all that styling code).